# TableView editing DB Table in javafx

Tags: java, database, javafx, tableview

I have read all the threads about editing TableView but i can't find the solution for my case. I raised this question because i have small app that deals with ScoreBoardCard which is mysql DB Table. So when i  enter the stage in which i should edit TableView when ever i press the column which i would like to edit nothing happends and the code for updating db does nothing because i didn't change the cell.Here is the code for my stage:

```
public class UnosCiljanihVrednosti  {

 static Stage stgAdminAdding = new Stage();

  static private ObservableList<Scb>data1;

  ViewAdmin object=new ViewAdmin();

  public static TableView<Scb> table1;
  static String c1; 
  static TextField perspektiva;
  static TextField cilj;
  static TextField mera;
  static  TextField ciljanavrednost;
  static ComboBox comboBox;
  static ResultSet rs = null;

public static void unosCiljanihVrednosti() {

     BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
      HBox hbox = new HBox();
    Label naslov = new Label("PERFORMANSE-NOVE CILJANE VREDNOSTI");
    naslov.setFont(new Font(24));
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hbox.getChildren().add(naslov);
    hbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Insets ins1 = new Insets(5, 10, 10, 10);
    hbox.setPadding(ins1);






    javafx.scene.layout.VBox vboxMenuAdmin = new javafx.scene.layout.VBox();
    vboxMenuAdmin.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    Insets ins = new Insets(5, 10, 10, 10);
    vboxMenuAdmin.setPadding(ins);
    Button btSacuvaj = new Button("Sačuvaj");
    btSacuvaj.setMinSize(100, 50);
    btSacuvaj.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
       sacuvaj();
    });

    HBox hboxTabela=new HBox();
    Insets ins3 = new Insets(50,850, 50, 50);
    hboxTabela.setPadding(ins3);
    table1 = new TableView<>();
    data1= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
     loadDataFromDataBase(table1);

    table1.setEditable(true);
    table1.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    TableColumn<Scb, String> column1=new TableColumn("Perspektiva");
    column1.setMinWidth(350);
    column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("perspektiva"));


    TableColumn<Scb, String> column2=new TableColumn("Cilj");
    column2.setMinWidth(400);
    column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("cilj"));


    TableColumn<Scb, String> column3=new TableColumn("Mera");
    column3.setMinWidth(350);
    column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("mera"));

    TableColumn<Scb, Double> column4=new TableColumn("Ciljana Vrednost");
    column4.setMinWidth(400);
    column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("ciljanavrednost"));

    table1.getColumns().addAll(column1,column2,column3,column4);


    column4.setOnEditCommit(event -> {
Scb scb = event.getRowValue();
scb.setCiljanavrednost(event.getNewValue());

updateData("ciljanavrednost", event.getNewValue(), scb.getMera());
});

    HBox hbox4=new HBox();
    Insets ins4 = new Insets(50,350, 50, 50);
    hbox4.setPadding(ins4);



    HBox hboxDugmici=new HBox();
      Insets ins2 = new Insets(50, 50, 50, 1450);
    hboxDugmici.setPadding(ins2);
    hboxDugmici.setSpacing(20);
    hboxDugmici.getChildren().addAll(btSacuvaj);

    HBox donjiHBox=new HBox();
    donjiHBox.getChildren().addAll(hboxDugmici);
    //Image logo=new Image("logo.png");
    //ImageView vLogo=new ImageView(logo);
    Button otvaranje = new Button("Dugme");
   // vboxMenuAdmin.getChildren().addAll(btDodavanje, btBrisanje);
   // menu.getChildren().add(menuBar);
    root.setTop(hbox);

    root.setCenter(table1);
    root.setBottom(donjiHBox);
    root.setRight(hbox4);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1920, 1000);

  /*   ViewAdmin.stgAdmin.setTitle("");
    ViewAdmin.stgAdmin.setResizable(false);
    ViewAdmin.stgAdmin.setScene(scene);
    ViewAdmin.stgAdmin.show();
    */
    stgAdminDodavanje.setTitle("");
    stgAdminDodavanje.setResizable(false);
    stgAdminDodavanje.setScene(scene);
    stgAdminDodavanje.show();

}

private static void sacuvaj() {
   stgAdminDodavanje.close();
   ViewAdmin.stgAdmin.show();

}

public static void loadDataFromDataBase(TableView table){
     try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        CONNECTION =DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
         data1=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
         ResultSet rs= CONNECTION.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT* FROM bsc");
         while(rs.next()){
             data1.add(new Scb(rs.getString("perspektiva"),rs.getString("cilj"),rs.getString("mera"),rs.getDouble("ciljanavrednost")));
             System.out.println(rs.getString("cilj"));
         }

         CONNECTION.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(AzuriranjePostojecihPerformansi.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
     table.setItems(data1);

 }


 public void getRow() {

    TablePosition pos = table1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);
    int row = pos.getRow();
    TableColumn col = pos.getTableColumn();

    String data1 = (String) col.getCellObservableValue(row).getValue();
    System.out.println(data1);

}
private static void updateData(String column, Double newValue, String id) {
    try (
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cs102-projekat", "root", "");
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE bsc SET  ciljanavrednost = ? WHERE  mera = ?");
) {

    stmt.setDouble(1, newValue);
    stmt.setString(2, id);
    stmt.execute();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.err.println("Error");
    // if anything goes wrong, you will need the stack trace:
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
}






}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
column4.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        column4.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Scb, Double>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(CellEditEvent<Scb, Double> t) {
                ((Scb) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setYourField(t.getNewValue());
            //updateYourData((Scb) t.getRowValue());
            } });
```

Comment: Mr Khalil, now  i have some paramters to set in my method updateData, updateData(name of the row in db table,new value that i changed in table view cell, id of the row).What shuld i put in the place of new value in parameter? how to call the new value

Comment: @Pera you can have the new value by casting (Scb) t.getRowValue()

Comment: ,still no luck:

Comment: error: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) S exist so that Callback<TableColumn<S,String>,TableCell<S,String>> conforms to Callback<TableColumn<Scb,Double>,TableCell<Scb,Double>>
        column4.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());

Comment: i beleive that the problem is in (TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()); cause the  output sais that is the line which cause to crash app.. but thanks for everything until know,i will seek to find something

Comment: Yes it is working when i delete, but when i delete tht line i can edit cell but i do not have anthing from my db  in that column

Comment: column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("ciljanavrednost"));

Comment: i did that, but when i put that code i lose option to change..i can onlu set my cursor  and click on a cell but i then i can;t change the value.Tnak you very much for trying.if you come up with anything write me.

Comment: you need a converter for the textfield -> double.        `column4.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
        column4.setOnEditCommit(t -> {
            t.getRowValue().setYourField(t.getNewValue());
            //update db with t.getRowValue()
        });`

Comment: @brian this allowed me to edit cell but still no update to db .. not after enter or after clicking on the other cell..what is the trigger for cell to know that it should start the method update

Comment: In the code of khalil and in my comment, it's commented out `//update db` since I didn't want to figure out your update method.  Just call your update with the correct values.  I was just pointing out that you can't use the `TextFieldTableCell` without a String unless you use a converter.  Also, no need for the complicated casting.